# Failing to compile Guava (v24.0) using Bazel (v0.10)

Tags: java, guava, bazel

I recently forked guava (v24.0, came out today) with the intention of contributing a parallel build system using Bazel for compliation and testing. I have it mostly working, but I'm having issues compiling the collect package:

Here's the error I'm seeing:
https://gist.github.com/perezd/4b39107381a9a032982fee3543c2f382

And I've pushed my WIP branch here if you'd like to repro:
https://github.com/perezd/guava/tree/bazel

command to repro (from project root):
bazel build guava/src/com/google/common/collect

Any ideas? Not sure why these sorts of failures would arise? Could this be a JDK9 thing?

EDIT: I'm running javac 1.8.0_151 (OpenJDK via openjdk-8-jdk package in ubuntu). Also, goes without saying maven compilation is working just fine.

EDIT: Here's the output of the generated params file that is getting passed to BazelJavaBuiler: https://gist.github.com/perezd/a730ff76f640f28fbf336174f48c8e8b

Comment: If I recall correctly, Bazel enables error-prone by default. That uses a fork of JDK9's javac, which has updated rules for generics. That might be the source of the difference between the builds.

Comment: The errors suggest that the Guava `Function` and `Predicate` aren't subclasses of the JDK `Function` and `Predicate`. Is there any way you could be picking up the `android/guava` copy of those classes but the `guava` copy of the `collect` classes? Maybe you're getting the `android/guava` copy transitively through some other dependency?

Comment: Err, I think maybe Bazel doesn't do transitive dependencies that way? Still, it sounds like you might be getting the `android/guava` copy somehow. Does `--verbose_failures` print anything interesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're [depending on](https://github.com/perezd/guava/blob/2d6a1cdda92e546928ac847c3e6c11f77e07eaeb/WORKSPACE#L17) the entire Checker Framework, rather than just the `checker-compat-qual`, the annotations-only artifact that [Guava uses](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/49454c4afb0c681bb3df519bc9635170f8be82c7/pom.xml#L224). The Checker Framework bundles an old copy of Guava, including only copies of `Function` and `Predicate` that don't extend the JDK's `Function` and `Predicate`.

Comment: excellent! I wish bazel would have warned me its already on the classpath. I changed to `    artifact = "org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.3.2",
` and that fixed it.